# Finish button not working while creating android project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create an android program but, every time I set it up it does not make a new project **successfully**, the project that is made has a huge number of errors..

All the specifications are given in the screen shots below...
[Making the Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwoTy.jpg)
[ADT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYbU7.jpg)

Comment: first of all migrate to android studio

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try opening it on Android Studio, an then making the new project there. Hope it could help you.

Comment: I have a plugin that needs eclipse

Answer (score 0):

you need to import android-support-v7-appcompat library then clean your project

Answer (score 0):

try to start using **android studio,** as suggest by developers/google Android studio for android Development, Android studio having much more functionality then eclipse and provide faster tools.
[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Comment: thanks, but the application has another plugin that needs eclipse

Comment: plz try to find same with android studio, as i know all the plugin or dependency/ library are there same as eclipe for android studio

Comment: lejos nxj is pretty outdated and only provides support for eclipse

Comment: i just seen that  you can also add the lejos pccomms.jar file in the Android Studio same as eclipse..., and im not force you to use Android studio just bczz your error and now mostly developers uses Android studio so.